# error en servidor: connect ECONNREFUSED

Tags: mysql, nodejs, express, mysqlconnector, express-session

Estoy haciendo un trabajo sobre node, mysql  tengo los siguiente codigo

```js
//la llave de la bases de datos
module.exports = {
    database: {
        host: '127.0.0.1',
        user: 'root',
        password: '1234',
        port: '3306',
        database: 'database_links'

    }
};
```

luego tengo las rutas

```js
const express = require('express');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
const path = require('path');
const flash = require('connect-flash');
const session = require('express-session');
const MySQLStore = require('express-mysql-session');
//aqui esta la base de datos de la applicacion que quiero hacer 
const { database } = require('./keys');
//initializations
const app = express();

//setting

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 4000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.engine('.hbs', exphbs({
    defaultLayout: 'main',
    layoutsDir: path.join(app.get('views'), 'layouts'),
    partialsDir: path.join(app.get('views'), 'partials'),
    extname: '.hbs',
    helpers: require('./lib/handlebars')
}));
app.set('view engine', '.hbs');
//MIDDLEWARES
app.use(session({
    secret: 'faztmysqlenodesession',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: new MySQLStore(database)
}));
app.use(flash());
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.json());


//GLOBAL VARIABLES
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    app.locals.success = req.flash('success');
    next();
});

//ROUTES
app.use(require('./routes'));
app.use(require('./routes/authentication'));
app.use('/links', require('./routes/links'));

//PUBLIC
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


//STARTING  THE SERVER

app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
    console.log('Server on port', app.get('port'));
});
```

y me sale siquiente error en pantalla
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
**Lo mas curioso de todo es que me estaba funcionando asta ahora cuando tenia ante otro error **que me decia que la funcion `res.render('auth/signup');` no exitia de express-session

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/signup', (res, req) => {
    res.render('auth/signup');
});

router.post('/signup', (req, res) => {

});

module.exports = router;
```

si hay alguien que me puede ayudar en esto

Comment: Por favor, tu error debe estar como texto, como imagen es dificil de ver.

Comment: en que imagen no se puede ver?

Comment: Para entender el problema de las imagenes, lee por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324)

Comment: dice la imagenes de captura de pantalla del error verdad . Dice error : connect ECONNREFUSED . no entiendo poque me sale eso cuando me funcionaba correctamente esta mañana  y ahora me dice que fue rechazado del servirdor.

Comment: El problema esta en que no te puedes conectar, mira que la configuración este bien, que el usuario de la base de datos tenga la conexión localhost y que ningún otro programa no te este ocupando el puerto.

Comment: Buenas compañero, ¿lograste solucionar el error? Estoy teniendo el mismo problema que tú, aunque es a la hora de conectarme a openWeatherMap. Los parámetros que le paso me funcionan correctamente ya que dicha URL probada desde el navegador o postman me funciona bien. Si diste con la solución por favor compártela para ayudar a gente perdida como yo. Gracias de antemano.